# How can I view an Azure CosmosDb using Pycharms or IntelliJ?

Tags: azure, intellij-idea, pycharm, azure-cosmosdb

[image]

I can see loads of drivers, but nothing for DocumentDB.
I did try searching for an appropriate driver, but I found nothing.

My DocumentDb is in Azure, so I have a URL and primary key, but I was unable to see how to connect via Pycharm using the "Data Source from URL" option.

How can I connect my DocumentDb to Pycharm (or IntelliJ) database explorer?

Comment: If those tools don't support the DocumentDB API (or MongoDB API), you're not going to be able to use them. Cosmos doesn't have a relational database variant, and every single one of those data sources listed is a relational database. You'll need to find a different tool to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmos DB is not a relational database, and you cannot simply connect to it as such.

It supports several NoSQL protocol variants: DocumentDB (native document store), MongoDB API, Gremlin graph api, and Azure Table API. Not possible to connect via a relational database driver.

If a tool doesn't explicitly support one of the above-mentioned protocols, you simply won't be able to use it, and will need to work with a different tool. And which tool you choose is really up to you (tool recommendation questions are off-topic).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I know CosmosDB is not a relational DB - I was wondering whether there was a plugin or driver I could install that would allow Pycharms or IntelliJ to interface with Cosmos DB. I can see from the list that there are only relational DB drivers installed, but I was hoping that I it was possible to install an appropriate driver. I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to CosmosDb from IntelliJ, DataGrip or other JetBrains software using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver). JDBC drivers are software components that allow Java applications to interact with dtabases. (I think that JetBrains IDE's are all based on IntelliJ, which is Java software). I think there are probably a few JDBC drivers around that allow connections to a CosmosDb database and run SQL queries.

For a specific connection example you can look at [CData](https://www.cdata.com/) who makes a [collection of drivers](https://www.cdata.com/solutions/bi/sisense/) including a JDBC driver that can be used to connect to CosmosDb from any tool that allows their JDBC driver to be used. They have [instructions that are located here](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cosmosdb-jdbc-intellij.rst) for using it with IntelliJ. I have been able to use the instructions located there to connect to a CosmosDb instance from [JetBrains DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) and run queries against the database. I still have some things to work out but it does allow me to create a successful connection and run simple queries.

Answer (score 0):

In September 2022, support for Cosmos DB [was added](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/intellij-idea-support/) to the "[Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8053-azure-toolkit-for-intellij/versions/stable)" plugin.